# sys.__stdout__ works but sys.stdout does not

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, stdout, nosetests

There is a function named redirect which temporarily redirects operations on file `source` to file `target`.

```
    def redirect(source, target):
    source.flush()
    fd = source.fileno()
    with os.fdopen(os.dup(fd), source.mode) as source2:
        os.dup2(target.fileno(), fd)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            source.flush()
            os.dup2(source2.fileno(), fd)
```

It was being called from the same module as

```
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
        with redirect(sys.stdout, tmp), nogil:
```

Upon compiling, it used to generate an AttributeError

```
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

at the line `fd = source.fileno()`.

But when I replaced `sys.stdout` with `sys.__stdout__`, there was no such error, and the tests passed successfully.

Now I'm really puzzled, why `__stdout__` worked but not `stdout`.

Comment: Are you running your program from within the IDLE environment, or perhaps from another IDE? I think if you run your program from the system command line, you'll get an actual file for `sys.stdout`.

Comment: I was running nosetests from terminal

Comment: Ah, yes the implementation of nosetests probably replaces `sys.stdout` with a `StringIO` object so that it can capture the output easily. It sounds like nosetests is not compatible with the function you're trying to run under it.

Comment: It seems `nosetests` provides an option for this. `nosetests -s` works.

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg mentioned in the comments, that wouldn't work. What I normally do is temporarily change my stdout.

```
@contextmanager
def replace_stdout(replacement):
    _stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = replacement
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = _stdout
```

And use that context manager with :

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
    with replace_stdout(sys.stdout, tmp):
```

This usages doesn't care whether the initial stdout has a FD or not.